# Unable to install package linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic

Tags: 14.04, apt

I get this message and I do not know what to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  

>E: The package linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic needs to be reinstalled
```

But I can't find an archive for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic) and then install it by:

```
# for 64 bit system
dpkg -i --force linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic_3.13.0-83.127_amd64.deb

# for 32 bit system
linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic_3.13.0-83.127_i386.deb
```

Comment: I did what you said, but now everything is slowed down, every animation, opening any app, or even opening folders

Comment: This worked great, and resurrected `apt-get` on one of my servers; just a note that the downloads section is at the bottom of the linked page (not the right), and you need to click through to the x86 or amd64 link to get the .deb download link.

Answer (score 0):

This command will reinstall the latest kernel and maybe fix your lag

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image
```